# How to write a logstash configuration for Json input file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I have json file adding below I am trying generate fields from the json data using logstash conf file. please suggest me how to write config create a individual fields in elastic search.

```
enter code here

"count": 15,
"value": [
{
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "hyperlink"
},
"web": {
"href": "hyperlink"
},
"pipeline.web": {
"href": "hyperlink"
},
"pipeline": {
"href": "hyperlink"
}
},
"pipeline": {
"url": "hyperlink",
"id": 90,
"revision": 4,
"name": "Name",
"folder": "\"
},
"state": "completed",
"result": "succeeded",
"createdDate": "2020-10-21T20:00:02.2490446Z",
"finishedDate": "2020-10-21T20:11:17.5898951Z",
"url": "hyperlink",
"id": 6254,
"name": "0.1.0-integration.1+47"
},
```

my logstash config is

```
input {
  file {
        type => "json"
    start_position => "beginning"
        path => "/home/dataflow/example.json"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^"
      negate => false
      what => "previous"
      auto_flush_interval => 2
    }
        }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

it is storing index like individual line as message..

my requirement is everything convert into fields

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please correct the JSON input you are trying to ingest. Does a file have just one JSON document or multiple ?

Comment: ideally, the entire JSON should come in a single line, or you need to handle separately like a multiline filter

Comment: yes, In my JSON file having multiple JSON document.